# Calculating the median

Tags: r, median, scientific-notation

I have following (exponential) values and want to calculate their median using R:

```
1.0584e+00
1.1618e+01
4.9097e+00
1.3595e+01
4.2209e+01
4.6901e-01
2.4911e+00
1.2441e+01
6.8128e+00
1.3581e+01
1.4373e+01
1.2828e+00
7.7811e+00
```

Here is what I am doing:

```
data <- read.table("path")
median(data[ ,1])
```

Due to values being in exponential, I am not getting the correct median. Alternatively, you may also suggest how can I change these values into normal floating point values.

Comment: You have to be more specific what is the "wrong" value you get? It would help, if you could provide a reproducible example, as this could have to do with the table you are reading, the indexing, data types, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you getting for the median. Seems to work for me. Maybe you have these as "factor"s and you need to convert with as.numeric(as.character())

```
> median(vec)
[1] 7.7811
> vec
 [1]  1.05840 11.61800  4.90970 13.59500 42.20900  0.46901  2.49110 12.44100  6.81280 13.58100
[11] 14.37300  1.28280  7.78110
```

Comment: Ooh yes, very elementary mistake